# Image is displayed on top of a MenuBar

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Dears,

I am trying to do an application using JavaFX. But for some reason, when I am trying to move an image, it is displayed on top of a MenuBar but behind the other panes. And of course, I would like to avoid that.

(Sorry, no image because I do not have enough reputation...)

I have already tryed to group then and to call the toFront() method but it is worst and change everything.

Here is my fxml

```
<MenuBar>
        <menus>
            <Menu text="File">
                <items>
                    <MenuItem text="Save"/>
                    <SeparatorMenuItem />
                    <MenuItem text="Return"/>
                    <MenuItem text="Quit"/>
                </items>
            </Menu>
        </menus>
    </MenuBar>

    <VBox>
        <Pane fx:id="imagePane"/>
        <HBox fx:id="buttonsPane" styleClass="white">
            <Button text="B1" prefHeight="50" prefWidth="50"/>
            <Button text="B2" prefHeight="50" prefWidth="50"/>
        </HBox>
    </VBox>
```

Here is my controller

```
public void enter(Scene scene) {
        Image image = new Image("images/square.png");
        ImageView background = new ImageView(image);
        imagePane.getChildren().add(background);
        background.setTranslateX(20);
        background.setTranslateY(20);

        scene.getRoot().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, mev -> {
            int y = 0;
            switch(mev.getButton()) {
            case PRIMARY:
                y = (int) background.getTranslateY();
                background.setTranslateY(y - 6);
                break;
            case SECONDARY:
                y = (int) background.getTranslateY();
                background.setTranslateY(y + 43);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you just show a part of your FXML file, but it should contain only one root element...

Comment: what do you mean by "move an image" ?

Comment: In JavaFX, nodes are rendered in the order of the parent's `children` list—assuming no modification of `Node.viewOrder` (JavaFX 9+).

Comment: No, this is not the full fxml. Only a part. The Root Element is a VBox.
"Move an image" = The image is center in the Pane. The user can move it up and down and can be allowed to move it out of the pane. But I would like to make sure that the image will be behind the Menu and not over it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I put the Pane with the image in a TablePane:

```
<TabPane rotateGraphic="true">
    <Tab closable="false">
        <Pane fx:id="imagePane"/>
    </Tab>
</TabPane>
```

To be honnest, I do not know why does it work but it is working :-)